# nodemailer send form(REACT JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodemailer

campo del useState

```
const [nome, cambiarNome] = useState({campo: '', valido: null});

const [email, cambiarEmail] = useState({campo: '', valido: null});

const [asunto, cambiarAsunto] = useState({campo: '' , valido:null});

const [message, cambiarMessage] = useState({campo: '', valido:null});

const [formularioValido, cambiarFormularioValido] = useState(null);
```

en la sección del onSubmit lo tengo asi

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/send", Datos,{
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },  
            data: Datos
          
        }).then((response)=>{
          if (response.data.status === 'success'){
               
          }else if(response.data.status === 'fail'){
              console.log("Message failed to send.")
          }
        })
```

```
intente un console log con los datos y me arrojan asi 

const DT = [nome,asunto,email,message];
console.log(DT); ===> todo el contenido 
capturado lo guarde en una variable

const Datos = DT.map(DT => DT.campo);
console.log(Datos); ===> entonces lo que hice
 fue para no estar poniendo 
nome.campo asunto.campo ... 
le puse un map y esa variable Datos la mande por axios.
```

```
Array(4)
0: {campo: "prueba", valido: "true"}
1: {campo: "prueba", valido: "true"}
2: {campo: "prueba@gmail.com", valido: "true"}
3: {campo: "test", valido: "true"}
length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
===================================
Array(4)
0: "prueba"
1: "prueba"
2: "prueba@gmail.com"
3: "test"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

nodejs express

```
app.post('/send', (req, res, next) => {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com", //replace with your email provider
        port: 465,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL,
          pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
      });
    var mail = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL,
      to: process.env.RECIVER,
      subject: 'Portafolio fotografias',
      html: `<h1>Details</h1>
             <p>CLIENTE:${req.body.nome}</p>
             <p>CONTACTO:${req.body.email}</p>
             <p>Asunto:${req.body.asunto}</p>
             <p>MENSAJE DEL CLIENTE:${req.body.message}</p>
          `      
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: 'fail'
        })
      } else {
        res.json({
         status: 'success'
        })
      }
    })
})
```

el problema esta en que cuando envío el mail me llega undefined y quizas pense que era porque los estaba enviando como arrays y no agarraba los datos correctamente.no se en que parte tengo mal escrita me pueden explicar porque sucede asi estoy practicando con envíos de formularios y validaciones asi que por eso estoy un poco desordenado y se que hay mejores formas de hacer esto mas limpio. pero por ahora solo quería entender y profundizar en esto de los envíos de formulario y validaciones **GRACIAS POR LA ATENCION**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que envías en el POST es la variable DATOS la cual te quedó básicamente así para enviar:

```
Datos = ["prueba", "prueba", "prueba@gmail.com", "test"]
axios.post(URL, Datos, ...),
```

Tal como lo tienes escrito, estas enviando un Array sin identificación.

En nodejs lo que recibes será el mismo array y no con sus nombres como objetos, que es como lo estas intentando leer.

Entonces deberás enviar un objeto:

```
const Datos = {
  nome: nombe.campo,
  email: email.campo,
  asunto: asunto.campo,
  message: message.campo
}
```

y ese **Datos** enviarlo tal cual lo tienes en el POST y te funcionará en el backend.

Comment: me ha funcionado. la verdad yo me complique un poco en esa parte gracias por la respuesta